# Strange behavior with Java Synchronization (Lock, Condition)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am just trying to model a simple readers / writers scenario.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ReadersWriters implements Solution {
    private final static Lock readerLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final static Lock writerLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final static Condition noReader = readerLock.newCondition();
    private static CountDownLatch countDown;
    private static volatile int readerCount=0;

    public static class Reader implements Runnable {
        private static int count=1;
        private int id = count++;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int readCount = (int) (Math.random()*20);
            while (readCount > 0) {
                readCount--;
                writerLock.lock();
                try {
                    readerLock.lock();
                    try {
                        readerCount++;
                    } finally {
                        readerLock.unlock();
                    }
                } finally {
                    writerLock.unlock();
                }
                System.out.println("Reader "+id+" reading ("+readerCount+" readers)");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*500));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Reader "+id+" done");
                readerLock.lock();
                try {
                    readerCount--;
                    noReader.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    readerLock.unlock();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*500));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            countDown.countDown();
        }
    }

    public static class Writer implements Runnable {
        private static int count=1;
        private int id = count++;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int writeCount = (int) (Math.random()*20);
            while (writeCount>0) {
                writeCount--;
                writerLock.lock();
                try {
                    readerLock.lock();
                    try {
                        while (readerCount>0) {
                            noReader.await();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Writer "+id+" writing");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*500));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Writer "+id+" done");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        readerLock.unlock();
                    }
                } finally {
                    writerLock.unlock();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*500));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            countDown.countDown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        int numReaders = 10;
        int numWriters = 4;
        countDown = new CountDownLatch(numReaders+numWriters);
        for (int i=0; i<numReaders; i++) {
            exec.execute(new Reader());
        }
        for (int i=0; i<numWriters; i++) {
            exec.execute(new Writer());
        }
        try {
            countDown.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could also use `ReadWriteLock`, but that's not the point...

My problem is that in the log, I see things like this:

```
Writer 4 writing
Writer 4 done
Reader 9 reading (1 readers)
Reader 8 reading (3 readers)
Reader 5 reading (2 readers)
Reader 8 done
Reader 5 done
Reader 9 done
Writer 3 writing
Writer 3 done
```

And I really don't see how this could happen... Is it just console prints that are getting mixed up or I am really missing something here?

Comment: The log looks good: one writer, many readers. What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, the question is specifically about the number of readers reported that's out of order...

Comment: readers are not ordered, they are just allowed to read

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's too late my brain is not functioning right anymore...

Comment: (I suggest using try-with-resource (form Java SE 7) to make the code a little clearer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is about these few lines right?

```
Reader 9 reading (1 readers)
Reader 8 reading (3 readers)
Reader 5 reading (2 readers)
```

which you expect it to be 1,2 and then 3 readers.

In brief, the problem is because your printing is not part of the synchronization block.

To give an example of possible cause base on your code, here it is:

```
writerLock.lock();
try {
    readerLock.lock();
    try {
        readerCount++;
    } finally {
        readerLock.unlock();
    }
} finally {
    writerLock.unlock();
}
System.out.println("Reader "+id+" reading ("+readerCount+" readers)");
```

for the above piece of code, in brief, update of `readerCount` is guarded by `writerLock`.  However it is possible that:

```
READER8                         READER5
(readerCount = 1 at this point)

lock writerLock
readerCount++  (=2)
unlock writerLock
                                lock writerLock               
                                update readerCount to 3
                                unlock writerLock

sysout of readerCount (3)
lock writerLock
readerCount-- (=2)

                                sysout of readerCount (2)
unlock writerLock
                                lock writerLock
                                readerCount-- (=1)
                                unlock writerLock
```

Not hard to imagine why the number looks strange.

Put the system out statement in the locked scope, just after readerCount++, will give u result expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your `System.out.println` calls in the Reader aren't synchronised.  What, exactly, worries you here?

Comment: Well, not really worried, but curious... :) Even the prints are not synchronized, you mean that one may read the value of readerCount, be "scheduled out" for some other threads to run and only later finishes the call to println ? I guess that makes sense....